# Asynchronous HTTP request in restfull Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, asynchronous

I have a java restful web service implemented, and I have one method in that ws that makes a HTTP request which takes like 3-4 minutes, I want to know if I can get any benefit of making that call asynchronous.

The thread could be used by another request or will be blocked anyway by the main call?

Edit: I am making a petition P to my web service A (a synchronous petition only), that petition is handled by thread T1, when the petition P call the URL that takes 3-4 minutes, would I get benefits if I make that call asynchronous (to the URL that takes 3-4 minutes). Benefits like the thread T1 will be able to handle new petitions?. 
If the answer is no, then are there another benefit in doing that call asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

It's not good to block a HTTP request for such a long time, because HTTP is synchronous.

Instead of blocking, it would be better to make it asynchronous and return `202 Accepted`. For getting the result you got two choices:

- polling (client periodically polls for a result)
- callback (notify client with help of callback-url)

For further reading look at this blogpost: https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2011/06/02/asynchronous-operations-in-rest/ or [Best way to create REST API for long lasting tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652627/best-way-to-create-rest-api-for-long-lasting-tasks).

Comment: Yeah I already knew that, but that does not answer my main question. I Updated the question for a better description.